# change font color to background darkness

Tags: objective-c, background, uicolor, uifont

In my app, you can change the background color of your view, but the fontcolor stays the same. Now my question here is if I can make the font color change from black to white and vice-versa according the background darkness.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the textColor of your UILabel or UITextView, for example

```
label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
```